# How to redirect to the same page

Tags: cakephp

In my Patients 'view' page I replaced a div with 'doctors/add' using ajax. And now I can add a doctor in Patients view page. But if any validation error occured it goes directly from my Patients view page. to  'doctors/add' page showing validation messages.
I Want it stay on the current page showing validation messages appropriately on input fields of 'add'.

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Doctors->create();
        if ($this->Doctors->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Doctor has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Doctor could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }

}
```

Is this due to $this->Session->setFlash in add() ?
thanks...!

Comment: show me your code.. or model validation..

Comment: Could you solve this? Where any of the answers given helpful? 
I'm facing the same problem and I want to know what worked for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$this->redirect($this->here);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls try this?

```
function add() {
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->Doctors->create();
    if ($this->Doctors->save($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Doctor has been saved', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Doctor could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));


        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'patient_controller_name', 'action' => 'view'));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view')); This also not successful.